# Formatting captured spufi results using JCL

Tags: db2, mainframe, jcl

How to format the input file as expected output file?

**Input file :**

BROWSE-- userid.RESULT

COLUMNS 001 072    COMMAND INPUT ===>
SCROLL ===> PAGE

--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+    SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNME, PHONENO                                    00010000
FROM DSN8C10.EMP                                                     00020000
WHERE WORKDEPT = 'D11'                                               00030000
ORDER BY LASTNAME;                                                   00040000
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+

LASTNAME         FIRSTNME      PHONENO

ADAMSON          BRUCE        4510

BROWN            DAVID         4501

JOHN             REBA     0672

JONES            WILLIAM       0942

LUTZ             JENNIFER 0672

PIANKA           ELIZABETH     3782

SCOUTTEN         MARILYN  1682
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+

LASTNAME         FIRSTNME      PHONENO

STERN            IRVING        6423

WALKER           JAMES    2986

YAMAMOTO         KIYOSHI       2890

YOSHIMURA        MASATOSHI     2890

DSNE610I NUMBER OF ROWS DISPLAYED IS 11   DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 100
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----   ---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
DSNE617I COMMIT PERFORMED, SQLCODE IS 0   DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
DSNE601I SQL STATEMENTS ASSUMED TO BE BETWEEN COLUMNS 1 AND 72   DSNE620I NUMBER OF SQL STATEMENTS PROCESSED IS 1   DSNE621I NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS READ IS 4   DSNE622I NUMBER OF OUTPUT RECORDS WRITTEN IS 30

**Expected Output file :**

ADAMSON          BRUCE         4510

BROWN            DAVID         4501

JOHN             REBA          0672

JONES            WILLIAM       0942

LUTZ             JENNIFER      0672

PIANKA           ELIZABETH     3782

SCOUTTEN         MARILYN       1682

STERN            IRVING        6423

WALKER           JAMES         2986

YAMAMOTO         KIYOSHI       2890

YOSHIMURA        MASATOSHI     2890

Comment: Please be more specific about how you want to achieve this? Manual edit? Running a utility, in foreground, or as batch job? Also, please remove the `JCL` tag, and add `DB2` tag instead.

Comment: @phunsoft Need to achieve this expected output from captured results of Spufi and it should be done via running as batch job using JCL

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here.  You appear to be running SPUFI interactively, you'd have to change that to a batch execution otherwise you'll be overwriting your userid.RESULTS dataset every time you use SPUFI for a different purpose.  DSNTEP2 and DSNTEP4 are documented in the IBM DB2 documentation, be advised their output is limited to 133 bytes in width.  This looks like it will work for your situation, but not necessarily in the general case.

After doing that, you have *many* options for reformatting your results, your shop's SORT utility, awk, sed, custom code you write yourself in Rexx, Java, PL/I, COBOL, C, C++, Python, and so forth.  Choosing one of these is dependent on a number of factors including what products and languages are currently installed in your shop, your own skill set, size of the result set returned from DB2, which products and/or languages are currently being phased out of your shop, and so forth.

If you're going to go the custom code route, you might want to code your SELECT statement in that language (if it's supported) and do your data retrieval and reformatting all in one program.

Perhaps a better solution to your problem is to use Syncsort, if your shop has that product.  Syncsort has the ability to execute a SELECT statement against DB2 and then process the result, reformatting as necessary.  Bear in mind that while the ability is there, your shop may have elected not to use it.

As is often the case, you are well served by asking your peers and support staff how this type of challenge is normally met in your shop.  Shop standards exist for many reasons, following them is in your best interest.